# SharePoint 2003

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, migration

I have data I need to migrate from SharePoint Server 2003 to SharePoint Online. Is there any tools that **will** support this?

I have done some research on avepoint, which unfortunately dont support this. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ShareGate says that they support 2003 as a source but not as a destination, so that should work.

https://support-desktop.sharegate.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000640728-What-does-ShareGate-Desktop-support-

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no direct way to migrate OOTB from on-premise to Cloud. And the 2003 version is too far away.

According to my research, the avepoint you mentioned really doesn't meet your needs, it only supports SharePoint 2007 at most.

You can try some other tools, such as josh's recommended.

In addition, you can refer to this:

[Vyapin](https://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools)

[image]

Third-party information disclaimer:

The third-party product that this article discusses is manufactured by a company that is independent of Microsoft. Microsoft makes no warranty, implied or otherwise, about the performance or reliability of third-party products referenced in this article.